# Notepad++ how to insert javascript or html comment based on type of code selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notepad++

I do work with html5, JavaScript, jQuery Mobile. Most of my files are .html which have both HTML and JavaScript mixed. When I try to comment JavaScript code Notepad++ doesn't insert /* */ but . Is it possible to make Notepad++ little intelligent to figure out what type of comment code to insert based on what type of code is selected?

Joe

Comment: Just use sublime with contextual snippets. It does exactly what you are asking for, and very easily.

Comment: I like that Notepad++ is free. I like Sublime Text but don't like nagging to buy it. What is a good free editor for HTML5 mobile app development?

Comment: Atom (created by GitHub) is similar to Sublime Text, but is completely free.

Comment: @citm09 check out visual code https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx or vim http://www.vim.org/